# SQLite .db file not empty (9 GB), but nothing shown when execute query

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I have a file .db of size 9 gb, but when I connect whit python (sqlite3), nothing is shown.

I was populating this file with a script which parses millions of XML files. At some point, I lost electricity and the computer shut down. the method .commit() was not passed but I still have data somewhere, because the file is of size 9 GB.

These were my configurations:

```py
db_cursor.execute(""" PRAGMA temp_store=MEMORY;""")
db_cursor.execute(""" PRAGMA main.journal_mode=OFF;""")
db_cursor.execute(""" PRAGMA main.synchronous=OFF;""")
db_cursor.execute(""" PRAGMA main.locking_mode=EXCLUSIVE;""")
db_cursor.execute(""" PRAGMA main.cache_size=500;""")
db_cursor.execute(""" PRAGMA main.page_size = 4096;""")
```

I expected to lost everything because I did not pass .commit() method, but I still have a file .db with 9 GB of data inside, but to which I do not have access.

Can I recover data in such file?

Comment: `journal_mode` off, `synchronous` off? And a power failure? That's like worst case scenario right there. You're probably screwed.

Comment: Running `.clone newfile.db` from the sqlite3 shell *might* be able to recover something, though.